# Error on : Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

Tags: apex

While using Map ,I have declared Like this;

```
   Map<String, List<order>> offerRuleMap = new Map<String, List<order>>();

    list<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, (SELECT Id, OrderId,Product_Group__c,OrderType__c FROM OrderItems) FROM Order WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :setOrderitemId1)];
```

and adding the Values to the Map

```
offerRuleMap.put(String.valueOf(orders.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) +  orders.Pricebook2Id+orders.Orderitem.Product_Group__c + orders.Orderitem.OrderType__c , new List<Order>());
```

It is Showing Error:

> Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

How to rectify the above error?

Comment: what is MapString?

Comment: Map<String, List<order>> offerRuleMap = new Map<String, List<order>>(); this is above line, while adding it is not showing Bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving the results into a List Variable. When you want to Access the Result set, you need to reference them by index. Example:

```
offerRuleMap.put(String.valueOf(orders[0].Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) +  orders[0].Pricebook2Id+orders[0].Orderitem.Product_Group__c + orders[0].Orderitem.OrderType__c , new List<Order>());
```

Or you can do it through the loop:

```
for(Order or: orders){
    offerRuleMap.put(String.valueOf(or.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) +   or.Pricebook2Id+or.Orderitem.Product_Group__c + or.Orderitem.OrderType__c , new List<Order>());
}
```

Comment: if it is Morethan 5 orders in the list, I want to add one by one through Map How @Klivakin

Comment: How to Declare and Iterated by Index Value Of List @Klivakin

Comment: for(Order or: orders){ }, this one is used for adding another list of Values using set, but Now I am using second time using Map the above one will work How @Klivakin

Comment: list < order> orders =[]

Comment: If you want loop through the Map you can use(If I clearly understand) for(List<order> orderList: offerRuleMap.values()){}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but should you put something like this :

```
for (Order o : orders){

  offerRuleMap.put(String.valueOf(o.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) +  o.Pricebook2Id+orders.Orderitem.Product_Group__c + o.Orderitem.OrderType__c, new List<Order>())
}
```